# GLSL OpenGL How to have more precise vector variables with doubles, e.g. dvec3

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es, glsl, shader

So far I can make a variable vec2 which contains 2 float variables, is it possible that I can make it contain 2 double type variables? i.e for more precise numbers.

So lets say I have a variable z

```
vec2 z = vec2(float, float)
```

Can I make those two float values become doubles?

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: Sure I just edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not. Double isn't part of the GLSL-ES spec yet (I'm assuming from the tags that we're talking about mobile). Here's [version 3.2](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/3.2/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.20.pdf) which is the latest. I also can't find any extension which would add support.

I rather suspect this is an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and that there are ways to solve the actual problem without resorting to double precision (which I think is what Novice was getting at in his comment).

Comment: Well I want to create a fractal in a shader, and I have done but the numbers get too small to process, and I thought that using double precision would let me 'zoom in' further